# jQuery: Validation errorPlacement

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

placing an error after an input box is simple and makes sense... but what if the error relates to a radio group and that group is within a table?

I want the error to show up after the table...

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using the validation plugin?

Comment: Yes I am. I'm trying to figure out the best way to attach the error to the next occurring ".error-trigger" class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the `<table>` it's in, then place the error [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) that, for example:

```
$("form").validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    element.closest('table').after(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow. Okay... I didn't even think to look for the "table". Thank you sir. Now everything looks nice and clean!